# Infinite series from Robert Bartle's book

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I need help solving this exercise about infinite series from Robert Bartle's "Elements of real analysis" book.

> Let $x_{n}>0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $n\left( 1-\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} \right)=a+\frac{k_{n}}{n^{p}}$ where $p>0$ and $k_{n}$ is bounded. Then the series $ \sum_n x_{n}$ converges if $a> 1$ and diverges if $ a<1 $.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! This is a consequence of *Raabe-Duhamel's test* which is a consequence of *Kummer's test*).

Comment: What I tried to do was to first set $ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1 - \frac1n\left(a+\frac{k_n}{n^p}\right) $, then use the approximation $1-x \approx \exp(-x)$, and see where to go from there.  Making it rigorous will be a bit messy.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think quoting an obscure test is what the OP needs.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: ‘Obscure’?  I learnt that rule when I was a 2nd year student. Anyway, the O.P. might learn a little more than the bare necessities. He also might try to see how the rule is proved and try to adapt it to what looks very much like another obscure rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has
$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1 - \frac{a}{n} + \frac{k_n}{n^{p+1}} = 1 - \frac{a}{n} + O \left( \frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\right)$$

Let's define $v_n = n^a x_n$. One has
$$\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n} = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^a \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^a  \left( 1 - \frac{a}{n} + O \left( \frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\right)\right)$$
$$=\left( 1 + \frac{a}{n} + O \left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)  \left( 1 - \frac{a}{n} + O \left( \frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\right)\right) =1 + O \left( \frac{1}{n^{\gamma}}\right)$$

where $\gamma = \min \left( 2, p+1\right) > 1$. So $$\ln \left( \frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}\right) = O \left( \frac{1}{n^{\gamma}}\right)$$

So the series $\ln \left( \frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}\right)$ converges, so the sequence $(\ln (v_n))$ converges, so the sequence $(v_n)$ converges : denoting $K = \lim v_n$, you get directly
$$u_n \sim \frac{K}{n^a}$$

which gives you the desired results.